# Dragdealer reset to first slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, dragdealer-js

I want to reset my dragdealer image slider by scroll down. When I scroll down - I want to reset slider to first slide.

```
  new Dragdealer('image-carousel', {
    steps: 3,
    speed: 0.3,
    loose: true
  });
```

I have multiple sliders and I want to reset them when scroll to next slider, so when I scroll back to that slider - I arrive at first slide instead of last slide where I've been.

[See demo](http://sedmica.rs/sajt/)

Thank you!